# How to get a specific collection from a large json file

Tags: java, json, jackson, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get a specific collection from a large json file but i don't want to make all the object structure on the json file because i only need the "calls" and "puts" fields...

the jsonfile is this: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/AEIS?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com

this is my class options... not posting getters and setters..

```
public class Option {

  public enum Type { PUT, CALL }
  @JsonIgnore
  public Type type;
  @JsonProperty("contractSymbol")
  private String contractSymbol;
  @JsonProperty("contractSize")
  private String contractSize;
  @JsonProperty("currency")
  private String currency;

  @JsonProperty("inTheMoney")
  private boolean inTheMoney;
  @JsonProperty("percentChange")
  private Field percentChange;
  @JsonProperty("strike")
  private Field strike;
  @JsonProperty("change")
  private Field change;
  @JsonProperty("impliedVolatility")
  private Field impliedVolatility;
  @JsonProperty("ask")
  private Field ask;
  @JsonProperty("bid")
  private Field bid;
  @JsonProperty("lastPrice")
  private Field lastPrice;

  @JsonProperty("volume")
  private LongFormatField volume;
  @JsonProperty("lastTradeDate")
  private LongFormatField lastTradeDate;
  @JsonProperty("expiration")
  private LongFormatField expiration;
  @JsonProperty("openInterest")
  private LongFormatField openInterest;
}
```

and i'm trying to get data like this...

```
List<Option> res = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(new URL(link), new TypeReference<List<Option>>() {});

for(Option o: res){
  o.type = Option.Type.CALL;
  System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Aaand this is the exception...

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
    at [Source: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/AEIS?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com; line: 1, column: 16] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["optionChain"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the json return from the source begins with a object property, "optionChain", which Jackson try to deserialize it as `HashMap`, but you expect a `List` after deserialized.

As you mentioned you only need the "calls" and "puts" in the json, you can use `ObjectMapper.readTree` to get the whole `JsonNode` first, then find the node of "calls" by `JsonNode.findValue`, and finally deserialize the node. Following is an example:

```
String link = "https://query2.finance.yahoo" +
            ".com/v7/finance/options/AEIS?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(new URL(link));
JsonNode calls = jsonNode.findValue("calls");
List<Option> callOptions = mapper.readValue(calls.traverse(), new TypeReference<List<Option>>() {});
```